# get complexity for karasuba algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence, master-theorem

I saw the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm that has the recurrence relation for karatsuba algorithm as:

> T(n) = 3T(n/2) + cn + d

and by using master algorithm, its time complexity can be obtained as `T(n) = O(n^log_2(3))`. I never worked with master theorem before. When I read it up on the wiki page, it appears that `T(n)` works with case 1, but how do we know that `cn (from T(n))`, in which `c` is less than `log_2(3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> T(n) = 3T(n/2) + cn + d

`c` in `cn` is not the same `c` that you would use for master theorem. Master theorem has n<sup>c</sup>, `cn` here would be linear where n is raised to the 1st power, so c = 1. Since **c = 1 < log<sub>2</sub>3**, the first case applies.